# What is the term for calling off a war when you are winning?

Tags: single-word-requests

If you're losing a war, you can *surrender* to end the war. In an *armistice*, neither side surrenders, but both agree to end the war. Is there a term for a side that is winning that has a change of heart and ends the war unilaterally?

A *ceasefire* or *truce* both appear to be cessations of hostility that are somehow less than an *armistice*. Neither appear to be unilateral.

I understand that it probably doesn't happen much, so there may not be a word for it.

As to why such a thing might occur, besides just thinking better of it or having an election that leads to a new direction from leadership, I could also see enough Pyrrhic victories leading the aggressor to give up on the war, but certainly not surrender or even enter into an agreement of any kind.

Comment: _Ceasefires_ are not strictly temporary, they just happen to be often temporary in practice.

Comment: A side cannot end a war unilaterally, whether it is winning or not. It can cease hostilities. It can say that it has ceased hostilities. It can do both. But the other side has to comply (or be wiped out) for the war to be over.

Comment: @Telastyn, I'm inclined to agree with you, but Wikipedia and some random online dictionaries all include "temporary" in the definition of both ceasefire and truce.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, if "cease hostilities" is what you believe is the best answer, go ahead with an answer. I'm not sure I buy into the compliance part. If the aggressor withdraws and the resistance has no means to pursue, the resistance isn't really complying, but the invader has indeed ended the war.

Comment: Korea has been under a ceasefire since 1953.

Comment: 207 000 Google hits for 'permanent ceasefire' would indicate that ceasefires can be either temporary or 'permanent'. What 'permanent' means (till the Day of Judgement?) is debatable.

Comment: @Oldcat, do you mean the Korean Armistice Agreement (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_War_Armistice_Agreement)?

Comment: Interestingly, that Wikipedia page mentions the *armistice* putting a *ceasefire* into place, but failing to end the war because no *peace treaty* was signed.

Comment: I've updated my reference to *ceasefire* and *truce*.

Comment: Your quote 'failing to end the war because no peace treaty was signed' indicates that at least modern wars have an international legal aspect. If a peace treaty has to be signed to 'end the war' (not necessarily end fighting, which might have already ceased, or continue beyond the 'end'), unilateral ending of a war is impossible (unless there is nobody left to sign on one side). Your query does not cover a possible scenario.

Comment: Dane - wikipedia is not a reference book, it's just online scribbles.

Comment: I think _surrender_ could be the answer to the original question. Either side of a conflict can give up and allow the other side to win. It's just that it's usually the side that's losing that does it, so surrendering often has that implication.

Comment: Barmar -- that is a **absolutely fantastic** logical suggestion. You really rock.

Comment: ...It would be if most definitions of this sense of 'surrender' didn't have the caveat 'because you know you are losing'. And the other side surely has to accept the surrender?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: *Permanent* in this context presumably means "has continued to this day and appears likely to continue indefinitely".

Comment: As we're encroaching on law here, and international law at that, I suspect that if the term 'permanent ceasefire' is acceptable there will be an accepted definition citing a definite timespan. And a maximum number of subsequent bullets. As recorded by specially appointed observers.... But legal English is beyond our remit here. This is why the original question is unanswerable as it stands; 'war' is an ill-defined term. I well remember the legal debate that was prompted by the statement 'We're at war with these terrorists.' The insurance companies had a get-out clause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say the winning force "***withdrew***" from the conflict, or one of its many synonyms: it "***bowed out*** of", "***exited***", or "***abandoned***" the conflict, "***discontinued***" hostilities, "***disengaged***" from battle, "***abjured***" the war, "***retreated***" and therefore "***foreswore***" or "***relinquished***" its formal victory, and so on and so forth.

None of these words have a particularly martial connotation (I don't think there exists a martial term which means "forfeit, but not lose") but that's easily addressed through context, as in the examples above.

Or, you could describe it the way my father did the first time I went to Atlantic City: ***Quit while you're ahead***.

Comment: Withdrew is an excellent thought, Dan!  Good one

Answer (score 2):

To echo what @Edwin Ashworth said; you cannot end a war without either:

1. Killing everyone who you were at war with (e.g. genocide).
2. Agreeing to end the war with the other side(s).

The closest I can think of is that one side "having achieved its objectives, no longer prosecuted the war".

Comment: #2 is called *capitulation*. Why that word isn't on this page I don't know... because it's *the* word for "calling off a war" (full stop; doesn't matter who's winning - everyone has to agree or it *isn't* over).

Answer (score 0):

There is a saying, *[it's time to declare victory and bring the troops home](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Aiken)*, attributed to George Aiken, former US Senator and Governor of Vermont. The sentence is actually a distillation of a longer statement made in 1966, relatively early in the Vietnam War.

> "The United States could well declare unilaterally ... that we have 'won' in the sense that our armed forces are in control of most of the field and no potential enemy is in a position to establish its authority over South Vietnam," and that such a declaration "would herald the resumption of political warfare as the dominant theme in Vietnam."
>   He added: "It may be a far-fetched proposal, but nothing else has worked."

[*Wikipedia*]

If the withdrawal of the winning side results in significant negative outcomes, you could say *[snatch defeat from the jaws of victory](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snatch_defeat_from_the_jaws_of_victory)*, which is an ironic reversal of *snatch victory from the jaws of defeat*. The inverted phrase means

> To suddenly lose a contest one seemed very likely to win, especially through mistakes or bad judgment.

[*Wiktionary*]

Comment: nice point about the political phrase "declare victory"

Comment: There's [another Gorge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_Accomplished_speech) with a similar quote... and a similar *'victory'*.